# JMeter doesn't launches the Chrome or Firefox browser

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

JMeter V5.3
Though JMeter lib and lib/ext has all the required selenium web driver plug-ins, when I triggered the Run button it's not launching the browser and throws the below error.

Not sure where am i doing wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
21-07-18 00:34:58,484 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2021-07-18 00:34:58,484 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2021-07-18 00:34:58,489 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2021-07-18 00:34:58,489 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2021-07-18 00:34:58,491 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2021-07-18 00:34:58,500 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2021-07-18 00:34:58,500 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-1,6,main]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:137) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.usingDriverExecutable(DriverService.java:272) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.getThreadService(ChromeDriverConfig.java:101) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.3.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:82) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.3.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:21) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.3.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:234) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.3.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:221) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:769) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:993) ~[jorphan.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) ~[jorphan.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:737) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:725) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:252) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_291]
2021-07-18 00:34:58,505 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2021-07-18 00:34:58,509 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

[image]

Comment: You mean under Options-->Plugins Manager. If so i did that way only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to [guava version 20.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/20.0)

Download guava-20.0.jar and copy to JMeter's lib folder

If you have guava-19.0.0.jar (or older), you need to remove it

Comment: @rpagadala are you sure? you copied guava-20.0.jar to lib folder and remove guava old jar? (and then start JMeter)

Comment: Yes I have added the screenshot at the end to the original post

Comment: @rpagadala Try removing guava-25 jar

Comment: Yes, removed  guava-25 jar  still no luck

Comment: It's working for me with latest JMeter 5.4.1, consider upgarding your version

Comment: Yes, It working after upgraded it to V5.4.1 . But I have only Installed Selenium plugin and 1 more that's it. It seems we need to instill only required plugins instead of all available plugins. Thank you user7294900

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have all the necessary .jar files under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (or suffering from a form of a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell))

1. [According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) (or whatever is the latest JMeter stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
2. Install **Selenium/WebDriver Support** plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/) - it will download and install the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) and all its [dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/3.3)
3. You should be able to use the WebDriver Sampler normally now